# Inherited scroll behavior when scrolling React Native FlatList

Tags: react-native

In my page I have two tabs and each tab has its own FlatList which renders two different items. The problem is, whenever I scroll the first tab, the second tab gets affected meaning it scrolls too even though I render them separately.

Here is my code:

```
return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {
          tab === 'public' ? this.publicPhotoList(refresh, publicPhotoIds, width) : this.privatePhotoList(refresh, privatePhotoIds, width)
        }
      </View>
    )

privatePhotoList(refresh, privatePhotoIds, width) {
    return (
      <FlatList
        refreshing={refresh}
        horizontal={false}
        initialNumToRender={8}
        maxToRenderPerBatch={8}
        showsVerticalScrollIndicator={true}
        numColumns={2}
        onEndReachedThreshold={0.1}
        bounces={true}
        keyExtractor={(key) => key}
        data={privatePhotoIds}
        renderItem={(data) => (
          <View style={{ flexWrap: 'wrap', flexDirection: 'row', width: width / 2, height: width / 2, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
            <ManagePhotoContent id={data.item} />
          </View>)
        }
        onEndReached={this._onLoadMorePhotoList}
        onRefresh={this._onRefreshPhotoList}
      />
    )
  }

publicPhotoList(refresh, publicPhotoIds, width) {
    return (
      <FlatList
        refreshing={refresh}
        horizontal={false}
        initialNumToRender={8}
        maxToRenderPerBatch={8}
        showsVerticalScrollIndicator={true}
        numColumns={2}
        onEndReachedThreshold={0.1}
        bounces={true}
        keyExtractor={(key, index) => key+index}
        data={publicPhotoIds}
        renderItem={(data) => (
          <View style={{ flexWrap: 'wrap', flexDirection: 'row', width: width / 2, height: width / 2, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
            <ManagePhotoContent id={data.item} />
          </View>)
        }
        onEndReached={this._onLoadMorePhotoList}
        onRefresh={this._onRefreshPhotoList}
      />
    )
  }
```

---

Edit:

Did some workaround by rendering null when the tab is not selected:

```
{
          tab === 'public' ? this.publicPhotoList(refresh, publicPhotoIds, width) : null
        }

        {
          tab === 'private' ? this.privatePhotoList(refresh, privatePhotoIds, width) : null
        }
```

The only thing I don't like about this solution is that, it scrolls me back to the top.

Any other solution is much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to add separate key for each `FlatList`

```
privatePhotoList(refresh, privatePhotoIds, width) {
    return (
      <FlatList
        key="private"
        ...
      />
    )
  }

publicPhotoList(refresh, publicPhotoIds, width) {
    return (
      <FlatList
        key="public"
        ...
      />
    )
}
```

Comment: yes it works, the behavior is similar to the additional info I posted above **(render null if the tab is not selected)**, I think I will just stick to this approach, maybe this is how react native FlatList works. Thank you so much.